# How to show has_many component in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

my show.html.erb file is like below.

```
<h1>details of policyid: <%= @policies.id %></h1>

<p><%= @policies.receipts.receipt_day %></p>
```

my controller is like below.

```
def show
    @policies=Policy.find(params[:id])
end
```

Model is like below

```
class Policy < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :receipts
end
```

```
class Receipt < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :policy
  has_many :outpatients
  has_many :hospitalizations
  has_many :surgeries
  has_many :others
end
```

Receipt Model has some record like this.

```
2.6.3 :005 > Receipt.all
  Receipt Load (0.3ms)  SELECT `receipts`.* FROM `receipts`
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Receipt id: 1, receipt_day: "2019-11-01", policy_id: 1, created_at: "2019-11-20 08:21:21", updated_at: "2019-11-20 08:21:21">]>
```

I would like to show receipt_day in policy show file. is this possible?
I suffered some errors like below.
If someone has experienced the same issue,please let me know.

```
NoMethodError in Policies#show
Showing /home/ec2-user/environment/calendar_test/app/views/policies/show.html.erb where line #3 raised:
undefined method `receipt_day' for #<Receipt::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00007f67fc0664e8>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to access a Reciept attribute by calling it on the collection. Your controller should look like

```
def show
    @policy = Policy.find(params[:id])
end
```

And then in your view where you want to see receipt_days on each receipt you can iterate through the collection

```
<h1>details of policyid: <%= @policy.id %></h1>
<% @policy.receipts.each do |receipt| %>
  <p><%= receipt.receipt_day %></p>
<% end %>
```

As @jvillian stated about N+1. If you're going to access any of the relationships on the receipt model you could eager load which ever ones you need to reduce hits to the db.

It'd change the controller/view like:

```
def show
    @policy = Policy.find(params[:id])
    @receipts = @policy.receipts.includes(:outpatients,...) #include any relationship that you're going to access in the view
end
```

```
<h1>details of policyid: <%= @policy.id %></h1>
<% @receipts.each do |receipt| %>
  <p><%= receipt.receipt_day %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: You might want to comment on eager loading to avoid an N+1 problem.